# What is wrong with the delete portion of my API?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, vue.js, mongoose

I'm in a web programming class and we are writing web server API's. I've currently implemented POST and GET, but I'm having some trouble implementing DELETE. What am I doing wrong here? I would appreciate a thorough explanation of what I'm doing wrong because I'm really trying to learn the material(unless of course it is simply formatting errors).

There are lots of portions that have not been implemented yet, so I'm sure there are many errors. Mostly I'm concerned with DELETE, and anything else apparent from my code that I don't understand.

I've replaced my domain name with fakeDomainName.com

index.html and script.js are in a public folder. start.js in my main directory.

We are creating a simple voting type api to practice, using a Node.js server and MongoDB database to store the information. Currently, POST and GET are working as expected, but DELETE is giving me these errors:

```
spread.js:25 DELETE http://fakeDomainName.com:3010/api/candidates/undefined 500 (Internal Server Error)
(anonymous) @ spread.js:25
e.exports @ spread.js:25
e.exports @ spread.js:25
Promise.then (async)
r.request @ spread.js:25
r.<computed> @ spread.js:25
(anonymous) @ axios.min.js:477
deleteItem @ script.js:65
invokeWithErrorHandling @ vue.js:1855
invoker @ vue.js:2173
original._wrapper @ vue.js:7416

spread.js:25 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 500
    at e.exports (spread.js:25)
    at e.exports (spread.js:25)
    at XMLHttpRequest.d.onreadystatechange (spread.js:25)
e.exports @ spread.js:25
e.exports @ spread.js:25
d.onreadystatechange @ spread.js:25
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
(anonymous) @ spread.js:25
e.exports @ spread.js:25
e.exports @ spread.js:25
Promise.then (async)
r.request @ spread.js:25
r.<computed> @ spread.js:25
(anonymous) @ axios.min.js:477
deleteItem @ script.js:65
invokeWithErrorHandling @ vue.js:1855
invoker @ vue.js:2173
original._wrapper @ vue.js:7416
```

Here is my code in "start.js", which is what I'm using to start the server.

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const multer = require('multer');
const upload = multer({
  dest: './public/images/',
  limits: {
    fileSize: 10000000
  }
});

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: false
}));

app.use(express.static('public'));

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/voting', {
  useNewUrlParser: true
});

var candidateSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  bio: String,
  numVotes: String,
});

var Candidate = mongoose.model('Candidate', candidateSchema);

//add a candidate to the list
    app.post('/api/candidates', async(req, res) => {
      console.log("initiated post request");
      const candidate = new Candidate({
        name: req.body.name,
        bio: req.body.bio,
        numVotes: req.body.numVotes,
      });
      this.addItem = candidate.data;
      try {
        await candidate.save();
      }
      catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.sendStatus(500);
      }
    });

    // Get a list of all of the candidates.
    app.get('/api/candidates', async(req, res) => {
      console.log("initiated get request");
      try {
        let candidate = await Candidate.find();
        res.send(candidate);
      }
      catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.sendStatus(500);
      }
    });

    //delete a candidate from the list
    app.delete('/api/candidates/:id', async(req, res) => {
      console.log("initiated delete request");
      Candidate.deleteOne({ _id: req.params.id }, function(err) {
        if (err) res.sendStatus(500);
        else {
          console.log(req.params.id, "deleted successfully");
          res.sendStatus(200);
        }
      });
    });

    //edit a candidate
    app.put('/api/candidates/:id', async(req, res) => {
      console.log("initiated put(edit) request");
      try {
        let candidate = await Candidate.findOne({ _id: req.params.id });
        candidate.name = req.body.name;
        candidate.bio = req.body.bio;
        candidate.numVotes = req.body.numVotes;
        candidate.save();
        res.sendStatus(200);
      }
      catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.sendStatus(500);
      }
    });

    app.listen(3010, () => console.log('Server listening on port 3010!'));
```

and here is my code in script.js, which is linked to my index.html page:

```
    var app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        name: "",
        bio: "",
        numVotes: "",
        file: null,
        addItem: null,
        items: [],
        findName: "",
        findItem: null,
      },
      created() {
          this.getItems();
        },

      computed: {
        suggestions() {
          return this.items.filter(item => item.title.toLowerCase().startsWith(this.findTitle.toLowerCase()));
        }
      },

      methods: {

        async postItem(item) {
            console.log("initiated");
          try {
            let response = await axios.post('/api/candidates', {
              name: this.name,
              bio: this.bio,
              numVotes: this.numVotes,
            });
            this.addItem = response.data;
          }
          catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
          }
        },

        async getItems() {
          try {
            let response = await axios.get("/api/candidates");
            this.items = response.data;
            return true;
          }
          catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
          }
        },

        selectItem(item) {
          this.findName = "";
          this.findItem = item;
        },


        async deleteItem(item) {
          try {
            let response = axios.delete("/api/candidates/" + item._id);
            this.findItem = null;
            this.getItems();
            return true;
          } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
          }
        },

        async editItem(item) {
          try {
            let response = await axios.put("/api/candidates/" + item._id, {
              name: this.findItem.name,
              bio: this.findItem.bio,
              numVotes: this.findItem.numVotes,
            });
            this.findItem = null;
            this.getItems();
            return true;
          } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
          }
        },
      },

    });
```

and finally, here is the code I'm using in index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>

</head>

<body>

    <h2>Hello World</h2>

    <div id="app">
        <div>
            <div>
                <input v-model="name" placeholder="Name">
                <p></p>
                <input v-model="bio" placeholder="Bio">
                <p></p>
                <input v-model="numVotes" placeholder="Number of votes">
                <button @click="postItem">Upload</button>
                <button @click="deleteItem">Delete</button>

            </div>
            <div v-if="addItem">
                <h2>{{addItem.name}}</h2>
                <h2>{{addItem.bio}}</h2>
                <h2>{{addItem.NumVotes}}</h2>
            </div>
        </div>

        <h2>Candidates:</h2>
        <div v-for="item in items">
            <div @click="selectItem">
            <h2>Name: {{item.name}}</h2>
            <h2>Bio: {{item.bio}}</h2>
            <h2>Number of Votes: {{item.numVotes}}</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--Vue and axios-->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.2/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/script.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: use can use findOneAndDelete instead of deleteOne it ....because if will first find and then delete the result .

Comment: I get the same error with this. Is the syntax the same except with the different function name?

Comment: as you can see in log

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in url  you  are not getting params  id its showing as undefined
`//fakeDomainName.com:3010/api/candidates/undefined` 
due to which it  is giving error if you will pass with as id it will work as well

````
//delete a candidate from the list
    app.delete('/api/candidates/:id', async(req, res) => {
      console.log("initiated delete request");
      Candidate.findOneAndDelete({ _id: req.params.id }, function(err) {
        if (err) res.sendStatus(500);
        else {
          console.log(req.params.id, "deleted successfully");
          res.sendStatus(200);
        }
      });
    });```
````

Comment: This still causes the same error for me. Do I need to pass id from script.js? If so, how would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I tested your node side with postman. "Delete" is fine. But as you see in the error itself
`DELETE http://fakeDomainName.com:3010/api/candidates/undefined` the parameter `item id` is being sent undefined, hence cannot delete.

In you `POST` request (on server/node side), you can perhaps add a `sendStatus(200)` to avoid post request being hung up.Also, You can get `id` of the saved item while saving the `Candidate`

Like this:

```
    app.post('/api/candidates', async(req, res) => {
  console.log("initiated post request");
  const candidate = new Candidate({
    name: req.body.name,
    bio: req.body.bio,
    numVotes: req.body.numVotes,
  });
  this.addItem = candidate.data;
  try {
      console.log("Await save...");
    let data = await candidate.save();
    console.log("Done");
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.setHeader('content-type','application/json');
    res.end(JSON.stringify(data));
  }
  catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.sendStatus(500);
  }
});
```

The response would be like :

```
{
"_id": "5dd38cb16f47912b40a1deef",
"name": "Ken Adams",
"bio": "bio",
"numVotes": "10",
"__v": 0
```

}

Comment: Thank you. I tested with a console.log and it definitely is passing undefined. I'm already trying to send the item id, so I guess I must be doing something wrong. How do I send the item id?

Comment: You can send it as a parameter in "deleteItem" in your index.html. Have you tried it yet? (I have mentioned in the answer how to get one while you `post`new item, you also get items' id with you `GET` request as well.

Comment: How do I access the item id from the GET request for deletion?

Comment: That would depend on how are you fetching items(I see you are displaying a list of items to select, how are you populating that list?), after you have added it or in other words how do you know which item to delete?

Comment: That is the center of my problem. I don’t know how to identify the item so I can delete it

Comment: The items are passing undefined because I’m not selecting them correctly